# EF - SaveChanges() saves 2 records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I've got a ASP.NET Web Application hosted in Azure. Interestingly, sometimes the application creates two records in database.

Could anyone please confirm whether I'm doing anything silly below?
Repository snippets:

```
private SomeEntity entities = new SomeEntity ();

 public void Add(SomeObject _someObject)
            {
                entities.EmployeeTimeClocks.AddObject(_someObject);
            }

 public void Save()
        {
                    entities.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Create snippets:

```
repo.Add(someObject);
repo.Save();
```

Note: I'm using SQL Azure for persitent storage.

I've got this JQuery to show loading, this may be causing this issue?

```
$('#ClockInOutBtn').click(function () {
                jQuery('#Loading').showLoading(
                        {
                            'afterShow': function () { setTimeout("$('form').submit();", 2000) }
                        }
                        );
            });
```

Comment: Looks fine.  What do you mean by sometimes?

Comment: There from 'empTimeClock' comes in?

Comment: Thanks @Pert, i've updated the question. should have been _someObject.

Comment: Looks like this is causing an issue? $('#ClockInOutBtn').click(function () {
                jQuery('#Loading').showLoading(
                        {
                            'afterShow': function () { setTimeout("$('form').submit();", 2000) }
                        }
                        );
            });

Comment: @jfar, it seems to happen when in debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server-side code looks good.

I think this problem is most likely caused at the javascript/client layer - I'd guess that somehow you are getting two form submits occurring.

To debug this, try:

- using Firebug (or IE or Chrome's debuggers) to detect the issue.
- using fiddler to check what is sent over the network from client to server.
- using Trace inside ASP.Net MVC to detect how many times your controller is being called.

If the problem turns out to be clientside, then you could fix this using some kind of check to prevent duplicate submissions - depending on your application's requirements, it might be worth adding this check on both client and server.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, exactly where I was heading. How do I implment the check to determine duplicate submissions?

Comment: Take a search on here - you'll find questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583267/prevent-duplicate-postback-in-asp-net-c and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635652/how-can-i-prevent-a-double-submit-with-jquery-or-javascript - and plenty more besides